# regex match after word

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to know how to capture text only if the beginning of a line matching a certain string... but i dont want to capture the begining string...

for example if i have the text:

> BEGIN_TAG: Text To Capture
>
> WRONG_TAG: Text Not to Capture

i want to capture:

> Text To Capture

From the line that begin with BEGIN_TAG: not the line that begin with WRONG_TAG:

I know the how to select the line that begin with the desired text: ^BEGIN_TAG:\W?(.*)

but this selects the text "BEGIN_TAG:"... i dont want this only want the text after "BEGIN_TAG"

I am using PCRE regex

Comment: Try a non-capturing group denoted by `(?:)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "selects"? You *capture*  the text into Group 1. It is already there. All you need to do is access the Group 1 contents. Is it PHP? Look at the [demo](http://ideone.com/JJSrj2).

Comment: its not PHP its in sublimetext. by "selects" i mean i want the text to be in my capture group

Comment: Does Sublime support lookbehind? `(?<=^BEGIN_TAG:\W*)(\w.*)$`

Comment: @CamilStaps Probably not variable-width look-behind, but `\W?` should be doable.

Comment: @melpomene right, of course. So `(?<=^BEGIN_TAG:\W)(.*)$` you get then, and if you also want to match without a non-word character directly after the text, you also need `(?<=^BEGIN_TAG:)(.*)$`.

Comment: this line seemed to do it for me: (?<=^BEGIN_TAG:\W)(\w.*)$

Comment: Camil Staps that worked! thanks

Comment: Camil Staps how do i select your comment as the solution??

Comment: You can now. :)

Comment: A solution with `\K` is more flexible: `^BEGIN_TAG:\W?\K.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Then, the text in the lookbehind group isn't part of the whole match. You can see it as an anchor like `\b`, `^`, etc.

You then get:

```
(?<=^BEGIN_TAG:\W)(\w.*)$
```

Explained:

```
(?<=             # Positive lookbehind group
    ^            # Start of line / string
    BEGIN_TAG:   # Literal
    \W           # A non-word character ([^a-zA-Z_])
)
(                # First and only matching group (probably not needed)
    \w           # A word character ([a-zA-Z_])
    .*           # Any character, any number of times
)
$                # End of line / string
```

Comment: Now, to support the optional `\W`, you will have to use alternation of lookbehinds: `(?:(?<=^BEGIN_TAG:\W)|(?<=^BEGIN_TAG:))(\w.*)$`. That is why using `\K` is preferable if the original pattern should be fully taken into account.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a positive lookbehind that does not allow unknown width patterns, you may use a match reset operator `\K`:

```
^BEGIN_TAG:\W?\K.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Si4CY1/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - in Sublime, start of a line
- `BEGIN_TAG:` - a string of literal chars
- `\W?` - 1 or 0 non-word chars
- `\K` - the match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `.*` -  any 0+ chars other than linebreak characters (the rest of the line) that are the only chars that will be kept in the matched text.